# paramiko does not work when forced command is on

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to execute some command by ssh.

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/home/kalombo/identity")
client.connect(hostname=host, username=username, pkey=private_key)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('pwd', timeout=5)
for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
client.close()
```

If ssh server has a forced command option, then script stops and do nothing while timeout is expired. There is a debug log. You can notice "Force command" line:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xb6d1bb4cL
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.0p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:[u'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa', u'ssh-dss', u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256'] client encrypt:[u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128', u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc', u'arcfour', u'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:[u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128', u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc', u'arcfour', u'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:[u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-sha1', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-256-96', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha2-512-96', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:[u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-sha1', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-256-96', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha2-512-96', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for 8.8.8.8: 54c2349797979732dda94989530c1f4
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH key 7d834324323429b09824eb
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Debug msg: Forced command.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Debug msg: Port forwarding disabled.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Debug msg: X11 forwarding disabled.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Debug msg: Agent forwarding disabled.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Debug msg: Pty allocation disabled.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
INFO:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 1 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
```

If i disable that option all works fine. Why does it happen? How i can fix it?

Comment: What is the command that is being executed in place of pwd? Perhaps it's taking too long to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Debug msg: Forced command.
```

There isn't a way to work around this. If the server is configured with a forced command for a key, then any session that you open using that key will cause the server to ignore the command that you're requesting and invoke the forced command instead.

Without knowing what command the server is running, there's no way to know why it is hanging. The forced command may be waiting for input from the remote ssh client, in which case it would wait indefinitely.

The forced command has access to the original command requested by the client, through the environment variable "SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND". The forced command could inspect this variable and invoke the command requested by the client, but the forced command would have to be written with this functionality in mind.